# SQL: How to select data from column that does not end in 'EW'?

Tags: sql

I am looking for a way to query data from my datatable that does not end in 'EW'. Currently below is how I have my query arranged:

`SELECT * FROM dry_mix WHERE note NOT LIKE '%EW`

When the following query above is ran, it returns a empty array. I would like for the query to return all data that does not have an ending with EW within my note column.

How could I fix my current query to return this data?

Comment: Please elaborate on "not working".

Comment: Please have a re-creatable example:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: [*It's not working* is simply not sufficient](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Sorry, I am new to all this but. Basically when I run the code, none of my data is showing but I know that the data should be showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax in most SQL variants would be:

```
SELECT * FROM dry_mix WHERE NOT(note LIKE '%EW');
```

Comment: This gives the same result as OP's original query. (And both have valid ANSI/ISO SQL syntax.)